# Failing to read text file content java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a java console application, which is supposed to have login interface for admin and normal user, reading and verifying the input against contents of a text file.

I however seem to be stuck at reading the contents of the text file, and it continually gives an error that states: "Failed to locate file"

Below is my code that locates and read the content of the text file.

```
 //Method for teller/shop assistant login
 public static void tellerLogin(){

 //loading and reading the text file containing the login credentials
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("the \\ dir\\myFile.extension"));
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String user = scan.nextLine();
    String pass = scan.nextLine();

  //String variables to hold the data retrieved from the text file
    String inpUser = keyboard.nextLine();
    String inPass = keyboard.nextLine();

  //Verifying the user input against the text file contents for verification
    if (inpUser.equals(user) && inPass.equals(pass)){
        System.out.println(" Logged in as Admin");
        tellerMenu();

    }

    else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect credentials");
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
 SEVERE: null java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\pasd\adminlogin.txt (The system cannot find the file specified) at  
 java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) at 
 java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) at 
 java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) at 
 java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611) at 
 kiosk.Kiosk.adminLogin(Kiosk.java:89) at kiosk.Kiosk.main(Kiosk.java:35)
```

Comment: `new File("the \\ dir\\myFile.extension")` is that actually in your code or did you just do this fo SO ?

Comment: I have the actual location in my code

Comment: Ok gotcha, based on the error it is not failing to open the file, but rather it is failing to even find the file - the full error should give a bit more info if you wouldn't mind including it in the post we can help you debug it

Comment: This below is the error.

SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\pasd\adminlogin.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
 at kiosk.Kiosk.adminLogin(Kiosk.java:89)
 at kiosk.Kiosk.main(Kiosk.java:35)

Comment: ok, so based on `D:\pasd\adminlogin.txt`, can you verify for us that the file is in the `pasd` folder of the `D:` drive? also be sure spelling is 100% correct

Comment: The file is in theat folder, I have also tried changing the location of the file and specifying the new location but still gives the same error. the spelling is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use an absolute Path file in here, then you need

new File("the \ dir\myFile.extension");

the \ dir\myFile.extension is the absolute Path;

Note example syntax for:

`windows system`:C:\1.txt,

`Mac or linux`:/Users/home/xxx.txt

if you set your file as a relative path, your resource file in your resources directory can be used: `YouClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path)`

E.g.

```
 String path="1.txt";//set your file path
    //get file resource
    URL resource = MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
    //if file not exist
 if(resource==null){
        throw new NullPointerException("not found a resource file")
    }
    //create file using path
    File file= new File(resource.getFile());
    //get file
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (file);
```

Specifically, for your problem:

1. you need confirm your file in path `D:\pasd\adminlogin.txt`,
2. you can change your path separator `\` to `/` for `D:/pasd/adminlogin.txt`;
3. suggest you put your `adminlogin.txt` in you project `resources` directory

this project is ab example for your problem :
https://github.com/lonecloud/stackoverflow/

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful and I am now able to proceed.